# Dockerfile PHP, NGINX and Composer

Tags: dockerfile

I'm having a difficult time finding resources for creating a Dockerfile to install a proper PHP, Composer and NGINX environment.

I can create a docker-compose container set, but I cannot get composer installed doing that. If anyone has any good resources to point me to, in order to write a full PHP, Composer and NGINX Dockerfile.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Just putting "php compose nginx docker" into a big search-engine reveals some existing docker files for this use case, like https://github.com/nanoninja/docker-nginx-php-mysql/blob/master/docker-compose.yml Maybe they can serve as a guide

Answer (score 0):

this is my docker file example for a similar scenario, I hope it helps. Feedback and ideas are welcomed !

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    software-properties-common \
    lsb-release \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    wget \
    gnupg2

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions (some are already compiled in the PHP base image)
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd json zip xml

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create myuser
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u 1000 -d /home/myuser myuser
RUN mkdir -p /home/myuser/.composer && \
    chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/mypage

USER $user
```

You can add nginx to this container but then, I recommend to use supervisord to control multiple processes.